# Populating Listbox with a List of objects

Tags: c#, list, object, listbox

Hi im trying to populate my listbox with values from an object of another class called produkt that has 3 string values. Each item in the listbox is suposed to have productname, a serialnumber and price and if the listbox already contains an item with eather the same productname or warenumber i want a messagebox to pop up. My problem is that when i try to to use my List.Add(newProduct)to add the object to my listbox as a string containing these values it dosent go to my listbox and when i try to print it it says Mediastore.produkt. I've tried many diffrent ways to solve this i've used toString to try and make the values of my object into a string. 
Any ideas how i can get my Listbox to show the content of List?

```
public void NewProdct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    string productname;
    string warenumber;
    string Price_;

    productname = ProdNamn.Text;
    warenumber = Varu_Nr.Text;
    Price_ = pris_.Text;

    List<produkt> List = new List<produkt>();

    if(List.Any( produkt => produkt.Name == productname || produkt.Serialnumber == warenumber)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Product with that name or warenumber");
        return;
    }

    var newProdukt = new produkt()
    {
        Name = productname,
        Serialnumber = warenumber,
        price = Price_
    };
    string random;
    random = newProdukt.Name + newProdukt.price + newProdukt.Serialnumber ;

    List.Add(newProdukt);
    Console.WriteLine(newProdukt);
}
```

Comment: Did you set DisplayMember and ValueMember in your listbox?

Comment: No i have not but im not sure how to do that since i declared that my Lista ( the listbox) is a List of products. 
if i change this wont my if(Lista.Any( produkt => produkt.Name == productname || produkt.Serialnumber == warenumber))  stop working ?

Comment: No it will working fine, just set your listbox.DispalyMember = "Name" and listbox.ValueMember="SerialNumber" and also you have another option override ToString in produkt and return Name;

Answer (score 0):

You can either define a list of produkt as the ListBox's Datasource and set the DisplayMember to a field.

Or you can add a ToString() method to your product class. This will then be used to display the products in the ListBox.

Comment: i declare that my Listbox(Lista) is a List of products so if i change this wont my if(Lista.Any( produkt => produkt.Name == productname || produkt.Serialnumber == warenumber)) stop working ?

Comment: If we are indeed talking about a Winforms ListBox it is a collection of object by definition and will be able to hold objects of any class and display them with their ToString() method.. If you don't provide one it will display the class name. Or you can define a Display Member. BTW:  I see no __Lista__ in the code you've shown us.

Comment: Yeah sorry its suposed to be
List<produkt> Lista = new List<produkt>(); 
And Lista is the name of my listbox.
It feels like this is sort of a wierd way of doing it that i change my listbox to a list it kinda messes with my brain but i asked my teacher and he said that this was the easiest way of doing it.
Do you sugest that i instead have 1 List and one Listbox and that they somehow are diffrent types but share the same variables?

Comment: _List<produkt> Lista = new List<produkt>(); And Lista is the name of my listbox._ This can't be right. You are declaring a List<T> which has the same name as your ListBox thereby hiding the Listbox? Also you never add to your real ListBox, as this would be `Lista.Items.Add(newProdukt)` or whatever the ListBox is named; And yes, declaring a class explicitly make it easier to expand it.

Comment: i showed him my code and he sugested i do List<Produkt> Lista  = New List<Produkt>(); so i guess he made a misstake then..

Comment: Make that : `public override string ToString() { return Name;}`  Note the spelling! C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Hi i can now see the name displayed however i can for some reason only have  / see the name of one object and everytime that i change the name in my textbox and click that name is displayed instead.
i did set Lista.dataSource = List; you think that might be an issue?

Comment: List is declared __inside__ the button click event. so it is always recreated. Move the declaration __outside__ and the new additions should all show..

Comment: shit im so stupid! thanks man all works now but i also want all my fields to show for example Name , Serialnumber , Price.
Is there some way to override a method and return more than one value ? i tried but i got all kinds of values.

Comment: Make that for example: ` {return Name + " (" + Serialnumber + ")  "  + Price; }`

Comment: I have a new problem and that is that the objects in my Listbox (Lista) is supposed to be seen in another Listbox called KassaSortiment that resides in a diffrent view is this possible?

Comment: Of course. If they should share the data simply make one the Datasource of the other: `listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.Items;` If data may be added, changed or removed independently you could copy them over or add them to both in the first place. either way all you need is to make them public and a reference to the other listbox and its container, probably a form. Many posts that explain how to do that..

Comment: To save an Item ( object) in my listbox do you recomend i use Serialization or is there an easier way?

Comment: Haven't been there for a while but I know that is a method that will allow for growth and is portable. And it'll be worth learning, too.